# Create new instance of a component when parameter changes

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a master-detail scenario, when the detail is a separate component that I use like this:

```
<ItemDetail Id="@SelectedItem.Id"></ItemDetail>
```

When the SelectedItem changes, I need to complete ItemDetail component. The DOM diffing algorithm doesn't make much sense. Besides, reusing singe instance of the ItemDetail component make it harder to load data based on ID, since there might be a lot of ongoing asynchronous loading that need to be cancelled.

Is there a way to tell Blazor to create new instance rather than setting the parameter?

Comment: Try adding `@key="@SelectedItem.Id"` to that markup - that will tell the renderer to create a new instance

Comment: @MisterMagoo, yes!!! it works https://blazorfiddle.com/s/u4vz7ikk . Post as solution, please.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `@key="@SelectedItem.Id"` to that markup.

That will tell the renderer to create a new instance every time the `Id` changes